# GIMP 2.6 compilation fails on Fedora 17 with fatal error: gegl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, fedora, gimp, gegl

yum installs GIMP 2.8 on Fedora 17, but I want to use 2.6 so I'm trying to compile it. However, I keep getting this error saying it can't find `gegl.h`, which is installed and on the include path:

```
[root@life gegl]# pwd
/home/james/packages/gimp-2.6.12/app/gegl

[root@life gegl]# make
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../app -I../../app /usr/include/gegl-0.1/ -pthread -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include   -I/usr/local/include -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gimp-GEGL\" -DGIMP_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGDK_MULTIHEAD_SAFE -DGTK_MULTIHEAD_SAFE  -g -O2 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wold-style-definition -Wformat-security -MT gimp-gegl.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gimp-gegl.Tpo -c -o gimp-gegl.o gimp-gegl.c
gimp-gegl.c:24:18: fatal error: gegl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [gimp-gegl.o] Error 1

[root@life gegl]# ls -l /usr/include/gegl-0.1/gegl.h 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 31086 Nov 18  2011 /usr/include/gegl-0.1/gegl.h
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you want 2.6?

Comment: You *don't* want gegl-01/gegl.h if you're building GIMP 2.6.12: http://news.slashdot.org/story/12/04/17/1826215/gimp-core-mostly-ported-to-gegl.  Q: Is there a "configure" script with your GIMP source tarball?  Did you run it?

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, I ran GIMP's configure with `GEGL_LIBS=/usr/lib64/gegl-0.1/ GEGL_CFLAGS=/usr/include/gegl-0.1/ ./configure` -- where in the slashdot article does it talk about gegl-0.1 or GIMP 2.6.12 -- the link is about GIMP 2.8 and 2.9.

Comment: There appears to be a bug with using the GEGL_CFLAGS and GEGL_LIBS environment variables. I set the lib dir in ld.so.conf and it compiled. FYI I did encounter one additional error in the process, but it was resolved by running configure with `LIBS="-lX11 -ldl -lXext" ./configure`

Comment: @S.Albano 2.8 is a major upgrade (3 years in the making) so there are significant changes. I'm in the middle of a project and don't have time to explore 2.8 so I'm going to stick with 2.6 until I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please re-run config:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H 
  -I. 
  -I../.. 
  -I../.. 
  -I../.. 
  -I../../app 
  -I../../app 
  /usr/include/gegl-0.1/ // THIS IS WRONG: it should be "-I/usr/include/gegl-0.1"
  -pthread 
  ...
```

Please also make sure your "-L" and/or "-l" library paths are correct at link time, too.